# querying the createdAt date by month and yeary only

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Is there anyway in mongoose to query the timestamps createdAt field only with the month and year? Or is there to save the month and year to only query it using that? Articles or code using that? for e.g I want to query the 2021-06-11T02:56:52.083+00:00, is there anyway that I only want to query that by the 2021-06 only?

```
{ timestamps: true }
```

Comment: use [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) with aggregation operators `$year`, and `$month` with `$eq` operator.

Answer (score 1):

Mongoose timestamps are Date objects and mongodb supports $gt and $lt operators on Date. so you can use following find query to get your desired period.

```
// Tue Jun 01 2021 00:00:00
let startDate = new Date(2021, 5);
// Thu Jul 01 2021 00:00:00
let endDate = new Date(2021, 6);

MyModule
  .find({
    $and: [
      { createdAt: { $gt: startDate } },
      { createdAt: { $lt: endDate } },
    ],
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution by doing this code:-

```
const date = new Date(req.body.date)
const month = date.getMonth()
const year = date.getFullYear()
const resp = await Appointment.find({
    'createdAt': {
        "$gte": new Date(year, month, 1),
        "$lt": new Date(year, month + 1, 0)
    }
})
```

If you want to include date so you can try with getDate() method as well.
I hope it will help